# The error happens when I get access to the .hdf file using the h5py in google colab

Tags: file, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, signature, h5py

everyone, I want to use the Google Colab to train the TSception framework. I have use the code showed to get access to the Google Drive. And it reveals that I have link the Google Drive successfully just like figure shows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEPV5.png)
And then I use `h5py.File("/content/drive/My Drive/sub_0.hdf", 'r')` to read the file in Google Drive. But it occurs the error "OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)".

Answer (score 0):

It's just because the hdf file is generated by HDF4 function, so it will occur erros when read it by HDF5 function. And the HDF4 and HDF5 function can write to the file which has the same suffix '.hdf'